# Solving differential equations with constraints

Tags: differential-equations, version-9

The problem is
$$ x''(t)=F(t) - kx'(t) \\ x'(0)=x(0)=0$$
with the additional constraints
$$ 0 < x(t) <a \\ 0 < x'(t) <b $$
where $F(t)$ is a known function and $a,b,k$ are given.
At the moment I solve such problems with the help of *`WhenEvent[...]`*.

**Example**:

```
First@First@NDSolve[{
  x''[t] == 10 Sin[0.1 t] - 0.1 x'[t], x[0] == 0, 
  x'[0] == 0, WhenEvent[x[t] > 400, x[t] -> 399], 
  WhenEvent[x'[t] > 40, x'[t] -> 39], 
  WhenEvent[x[t] < 0, x[t] -> 1], 
  WhenEvent[x'[t] < -40, x'[t] -> -39]}, 
 x, {t, 0, 200}, 
 MaxSteps -> 50000];
Plot[{x[t] /. %, 10 x'[t] /. %}, {t, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"x[t]", "x'[t]"}, ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image: Plot of x, x']

What is the proper way to solve this type of problem?

Comment: It's doing what it's specified to my understanding. Do you want the variables to remain at boundaries until force changes direction? Do you want perhaps the force to change direction upon hitting constraints? In that case you must introduce force as additional (discrete) variable in the equations of `NDSolve`.

Comment: BoLe, yes, I want the variables to remain at boundaries until force changes direction.

Comment: I did something for `x[t]`, try and stretch that to `x'[t]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that can be done. I don't know if you'll love this solution though.

```
{s, a} = NDSolveValue[{
   x''[t] == alive[t] 10 Sin[0.1 t] - 0.1 x'[t],
   x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0,
   alive[0] == 1,
   speed[0] == 0,
   WhenEvent[x[t] > 400, {
     speed[t] -> x'[t], x'[t] -> 0, alive[t] -> 0}],
   WhenEvent[Sin[.1 t] < 0, {
     x'[t] -> -speed[t], alive[t] -> 1}],
   WhenEvent[x[t] < 0, {
     speed[t] -> x'[t], x'[t] -> 0, alive[t] -> 0}],
   WhenEvent[Sin[.1 t] > 0, {
     x'[t] -> -speed[t], alive[t] -> 1}]},
  {x, alive},
  {t, 0, 100},
  DiscreteVariables -> {alive, speed}]
```

Roughly, I stored the first derivative and temporarily killed it together with force and then restored both at the appropriate moment.

```
Plot[{s[t], 300 a[t]},
 {t, 0, 100},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!
It works, but I have 18 variables with constraints so it will be very hard.

Comment: @KamovSergey If the constraints form a pattern of some sort you can encode you might want to look how to automate equations (`WhenEvent` is part of equation). You can do that. See help on `WhenEvent`, then *Applications* > *Bouncing Balls*. Or you could `MapThread` over the specification matrix. It shouldn't be hard to set up the whole problem elegantly I think.